# dismissViewControllerAnimated: not animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm working with [SVWebViewController](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController). When I present the view controller here

```
SVModalWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVModalWebViewController alloc] initWithAddress:address];
webViewController.webDelegate = self;

[self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The view controller slides up from the bottom, as expected. However, when the view controller is dismissed, calling

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

The view controller simply disappears. No slide animation down. Any thoughts?

**EDIT**
It turns out a lot of presentation animations aren't displaying correctly in the application. Some pushes on the navigation controller aren't sliding in or sliding out (but some are). They just appear.

Comment: In which view controller do you call [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

Comment: And do you have any other code that you run at the same time?

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; is called in SVWebViewController. When the SVModalWebViewController is initialized, it sets an instance of SVWebViewController to be its root view controller. @Wain - no other code is running at the same time.

Comment: Just double checking... are you calling this from the main thread?

Comment: Yeah - calling from the main thread

Comment: What iOS version are you testing on and are you using a device or simulator?

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder - Testing on iOS 6.1 and the problem occurs on both the device and simulator

Comment: @bdev Are you using storyboards?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique no storyboards in the projects

Comment: Are you setting `modalPresentationStyle` anywhere on your code?

Comment: Is "self" embedded in a UINavigationController?

Comment: @ArminM what do you mean by embedded?

Comment: I think you should include more of the code you have and explain exactly how are you initializing your VCs, which VC is calling the methods above, and where in your code are you calling dismiss. It's hard to come up with a solution when the situation is not clear. From what you have right now, it should work. I created a test project and copied your situation and it worked just fine.

Comment: Look at Saleh's answer below. You might have the same problem. Are you doing heavy computation on the main thread when you call dismiss?

Comment: Are all your didAppear, willAppear, didDisappear etc.. methods calling super?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

This should be in SVModalWebViewController not SVWebViewController

**EDIT**: Instead of modally segueing to the SVWebViewController you should push:

```
SVWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVWebViewController alloc] initWithAddress:@"http://google.com"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

And instead of dismissing you should:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I tried calling from SVModalWebViewController but the behavior is the same.

Comment: The web view controller is intended to be presented modally from a view controller that is handled by a navigation controller (not presented as the next view in a navigation controller)

Comment: @bdev Is SVModalWebViewController a navigation controller?

Comment: Yes, SVModalWebViewController is a navigation controller

Comment: Try presenting SVWeb instead of SVModal.

Comment: No - 'SVWebViewController needs to be contained in a UINavigationController. If you are presenting SVWebViewController modally, use SVModalWebViewController instead.'

Answer (score 0):

From SVWebViewController `viewWillAppear:`:

> SVWebViewController needs to be contained in a
>   UINavigationController. If you are presenting SVWebViewController
>   modally, use SVModalWebViewController instead.

1. Is your main view controller contained in a navigation controller? If not, this could possibly cause the other animation issues you're facing.
2. The dismissal should be from the displayed `modalViewController`.

Comment: 1. SVModalWebViewController is a navigation controller. Its root view controller is set to be an instance of SVWebViewController.
2. [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; is called in the SVWebViewController controller; I've attempted to call this in SVModalWebViewController, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: I understand you create an instance of a SVWebViewController to be the root viewController, when you initialize the modalViewController, right? shouldnt you use the previous controller you presented the modal from?

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me when the destination view controller loads a big picture or background

Comment: The web view controller is not loading an image.